# How to interpret weights of a PLS SEM model

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, partial-least-squares

I made a PLS SEM model using smartPLS, consisting only of formative constructs. I managed to get weights out of the software, which all had excellent t values. The only thing is, I am not entirely sure how to interpret these values. Unfortunately, the internet cannot provide me with an unambiguously answer. I hope you guys can help me out. This is the model [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just interpret the PLS coefficients as generic regression coefficients. But, since the coefficient links two constructs, it's not really necessary to interpret the exact value of the coefficient (such as 0.321). Simply, you can say there is a positive or negative effect of X on Y based on the sign of the coefficient. To check if such effect is statistically significant, you can look at the t-statistic usually using a bootstrap.

A book for reference: https://www.smartpls.com/documentation/learn-pls-sem-and-smartpls/pls-sem-book